# Moderator bias and stifling of discussion on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators, moderator-abilities

Recently I have come across instances of moderators being biased and trying to stifle the discussion through their special privileges on Stack Exchange sites (especially if the point of view or discussion is against their own personal views and they are involved in it).

The problem is that there are many policies about what can be posted and what is not allowed which can be interpreted and justified by a moderator in his/her favor as those are quite subjective and open to interpretation. They use those policies as an excuse to close discussions or hinder users who they might have a personal bias against due to some past interactions.

What can be done to mitigate this problem and what steps can a normal user take to discourage such kind of behavior?

Comment: Did you try posting on their per-site meta? Or is the bias here on MSE?

Comment: Do you mean formal ("diamond") moderators?

Comment: Discussion where? On meta sites?

Comment: yes (on sub-sites not meta)

Comment: Without mentioning particular sites, what kind of sites?

Comment: let's say humanities related

Answer (score 12):

> What can be done to mitigate this problem and what steps can a normal user take to discourage such kind of behavior?

You can discourage closing of your posts through being an exemplary user.

Make sure you know the rules of the site before trying to post. Each site has their own `/help/on-topic` part in the help center, where you can often also find links to relevant meta discussions and/or checklists for writing a great question.

One thing to realize is that these sites aren't for discussion, but for questions and answers. Moderators are likely to close your posts on a main site if you're trying to post discussions.

If you do post your discussions on the meta sites (where they belong) like an exemplary user, make sure they are constructive. Leave your feelings out of it, make your posts as neutral as possible. For example, instead of saying moderators are biased and stifling discussion, focus on the fact that they are closing discussion questions and trying to understand why those discussions don't have a place on the site you asked them on.

Comment: Sometimes what can be allowed or disallowed can be interpreted quite subjectively. When one sees double standards it is difficult to 'keep feelings out' (part of being a human being I guess). It might be that some other post has been tolerated even though it supposedly violates the policy and one's own post being judged on a different standard just because the moderator thinks that way or chooses to interpret the post that way.

Comment: @cometraza in that case, meta is still your best bet. But don't be surprised if the other question is closed too, nothing is done because the other question is old and yours new and things have changed in the meanwhile, or if there's a nuance that you're just unaware of... It's okay to say 'Hey, I'm confused because due to X I thought Y would float here as well, what did I miss', it's less okay to come in and say that your question must've been closed due to bias and misinterpretation of the rules.

Comment: you are assuming that moderator can't be biased and always has some good reasons for closure while that is obviously not the case. And the posts I am talking about are only recent posts. I can go into details but those are specific to each case. The problem of subjective interpretation remains. Anyways just want to say that all this is quite discouraging tbh.

Comment: They're not assuming anything @cometraza, they're trying to remain neutral, and give both parties, user and moderator, the benefit of the doubt. Without going into specifics, there's not much to be done here. You clearly feel wronged about a closure or two, and it may very well be fully justified- but speaking in ambiguous general terms and complaining about policy instead of the specific incidents isn't coming across as constructive, and you should probably take this discussion into specifics, likely with the community most closely involved with your closed posts rather than here on Meta.SE.

Comment: @zcoop98 an acknowledgment that the problem exists would have helped. anyways this was more to highlight this thing in the community. I don't know how many users come across similar experiences.